Cannot build ROS2 on Mac with python 3.12
So I am trying to build ROS2 on my Mac Silicon with python version 3.12 but I am running into unexpected errors.
Firstly, I followed the exact steps on this site to build ROS2 Jazzy :
I already had developer tools and homebrew installed and other prerequisites checked. I had to update setuptools on python because I got this error while running the vcs command:
AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
I then cloned the repos and got the ROS2 code but building is not working out because running the colcon command calls a python file with the statement:
from imp import ...
but python 3.12 does not contain the imp module and has replaced it with importlib (with different functions). So, I tried downgrading my python from 3.12 to 3.10, 3.9 and even 3.8 using pyenv but that also did not work. I then tried making a virtual environment using venv and building the ROS code in that environment, but everything gives the same error mentioned above (cmake is somehow finding the latest python version even if I use the solutions given here).
Without building the code, I cannot setup the environment (I can run the command but it does not change anything) and when I run any command with ros2 in the start, it tells me:
zsh: command not found: ros2
Am I supposed to change the python file in some way to substitute imp with importlib?

try to look at this solution :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77364550/attributeerror-module-pkgutil-has-no-attribute-impimporter-did-you-mean
